# How can we download file from url and save that file inside localstorage in react js

Tags: reactjs

i have an URL which on click download me a  file in my computer local but what i want is to store that file in local-storage of my browser not in my computer local in my React app

Comment: url : https://connect.emgsrv.com/D7huMcppWWRaAKMdafZW/D7huMcppWWRaAKMdafZW.CSV

Answer (score 0):

try using localStorage.setItem(key : value) to store value
and to get value localStorage.getItem(key)

Ex: localStorage.setItem("urlcontent", value)
localStorage.getItem("urlContent")

for key give a name and for value store downloaded URL content, it is not best practice to store data inside the browser, the browser has 5MB capacity of storage.
check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to download a file we create a new a tag and set the url and href to download it as below:

```
 const link = document.createElement("a");

        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([action.payload.canvasJSON], { type: "application/json" }));
        link.download = Math.random().toFixed(3) + ".json";
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
```

If you want to save the content of the file you download in localStorage or Cookies, you just set the content or any information you need like below:

```
 const link = document.createElement("a");

        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([action.payload.canvasJSON], { type: "application/json" }));

        localStorage.setItem(filename, link.href);
        link.download = Math.random().toFixed(3) + ".json";
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Of course, you can use other browser storage like cookies and indexDB to achieve the same goal, but beware of that third-party cookies will not be supported in the following year 2023.

Refer to: https://www.cookiebot.com/en/google-third-party-cookies/